# Cascading updates for multiple JComboBoxes

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, messagebox, cascade

I'm currently busy with a program where a user selects information provided in JComboBoexs to get a monitor fitting their selected specifications.

The order of selections is:
Aspect Ratio,
Panel Type,
Variable refresh rate,
Curved,
Resolution,
Response Time,
Final Display

All this information is gathered from a database and the first option affects the next. So aspect ratio will check that database for all distinct options and then gives those options. Then when you select the next option(Panel Type), then I run a query that takes in mind the first selection of Aspect Ratio. This goes on until the end of the options.

So my question is. How would I program it so that if the user changes something below the order(for example they have filled in information till curved, but then decide to change aspect ratio), the program will first prompt the user that changing this will remove x amount of information(Reseting everything below aspect ration back to blank for example) and then they decide if they want to or not and if they do it will cascade update all the other JComboBoxes back to waiting for the information again from the previous JComboBox.

The image is showing the layout of the buttons used to swap between the screens. From Aspect ratio to Final Display.

[Link to visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYXsT.png)

Comment: [Many similar questions on cascading changes in multiple comboboxes](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+change+jcombobox+contents+based+on+selection+other+JCombobox+site:stackoverflow.com). Please check out my search strategy as most such questions have already been asked repeatedly on this site.

Comment: As for your other questions, you simply write code that follows that logic. I'm positive that with a little effort you will easily achieve this goal.

Comment: Thank you, put me in the right direction. Still learning a lot, my school did not teach me much.

Comment: Re, "my school did not teach me much" -- expect that. The brunt of the responsibility for learning to code is always mostly on the coder him/her-self.

Comment: So I see know you are a prolific programmer from your profile. I do not know your background in computers, but does a website where you pick 3 games and select specs for a monitor and it generates a completely built compute spec list(This is an oversimplification) sound like something that you think the gaming community would like. I plan to link it to the Amazon affiliate program as well. Thoughts. Again just want to say thank you.